# Plesk Api to create a new domain with Hosting type

Tags: php, plesk

I am new to plesk and till now I have been able to create a new domain in plesk using the API. I have also created a skeleton folder. Now I want to add a hosting type to the new domain which gets created via the API.

I have the packet to create new domain like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet>
  <webspace>
    <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>ezb2550.info</name>
        <ip_address>10.64.2.30</ip_address>
      </gen_setup>
    </add>
  </webspace>
</packet>
```

This creates a new domain but does not add a hosting type. How can I add a Hosting type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create by hosting plan:

```
<packet>
  <webspace>
    <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>ezb2550.info</name>
        <ip_address>10.64.2.30</ip_address>
      </gen_setup>
      <plan-name>Default Domain</plan-name>
    </add>
  </webspace>
</packet>
```

To create with custom virtual hosting settings(pay attention for "[vrt_hst](http://download1.parallels.net/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/index.htm?fileName=39967.htm)" it's a hosting type):

```
<packet>
<webspace>
    <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>ezb2550.info</name>
        <ip_address>10.64.2.30</ip_address>
      </gen_setup>
      <hosting>
        <vrt_hst>
          <property>
            <name>ftp_login</name>
            <value>illusion</value>
          </property>
          <property>
            <name>ftp_password</name>
            <value>qweqwe</value>
          </property>
        </vrt_hst>
      </hosting>
    </add>
  </webspace>
</packet>
```

Possible hosting types are **vrt_hst**(Virtual Hosting), **std_fwd**(Standard forwarding), and **frm_fwd**(Frame forwarding)

Just in case, always check image of "[request packet structure](http://download1.parallels.net/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/)" it actually describes all of possible options.